Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string "" to bytes calldata requested
I have a problem when I try to compile my solidity file. I know where the problem is, it's the function checkUpkeep and performUpkeep; but I don't know how exactly is the problem between the state the function and calldata and memory. That's the code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/KeepersVRFConsumer.sol";

error Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
error Raffle__TransferFailed();
error Raffle__NotOpen();
error Raffle_UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalnce, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);

contract Raffle is VRFConsumerBaseV2, KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    enum RaffleState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    }

    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    address private s_recentWinner;
    RaffleState private s_raffleState;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;

    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__NotEnoughETHEntered();
        }
        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__NotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));

        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that the Chainlink Keeper nodes call
     * they look for the `upkeepNeeded` to return true.
     * The following should be true in order to be return true;
     * 1. Our time interval should have passed
     * 2. The lottery should have at least 1 player, and have some ETH
     * 3. Our subscription is funded with LINK
     * 4. The lottery should be in "open" state
     */
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes calldata /*checkData*/
    ) public override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
        bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval;
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle_UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }

        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 /*requestId*/,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.OPEN;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Raffle__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_entranceFee;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentWinner;
    }
}

The error that appears is the next one:
Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string "" to bytes calldata requested.

How can I solve it? This is from tutorial of Patrick Collins but some libraries change so I'm trying to make the course again
I search the solution by Internet but all solutions I found, didn't work.
Finally, somebody could help me and that's the solution for the function checkUpkeep:
function checkUpkeep(
    bytes memory /*checkData*/
)
    public
    view
    override
    returns (
        bool upkeepNeeded,
        bytes memory /* performData */
    )
{
    bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
    bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval;
    bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
    bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
    upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
    return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0");
}

